# Java convert list of string with comma separated values to list of objects

Tags: class, collections, java-8

I'd like to convert a json array of person

```
persons: [
  {"1, Franck, 1980-01-01T00:00:00"},
  {"2, Marc, 1981-01-01T00:00:00"}
]
```

To a list of Person object using this class:

```
class Person {
 private Integer id;
 private String name;
 private Date dateOfBirth;

 // getter and setter
}
```

Would it be possible to use a converter and Java 8 to do it?

```
public Person convert(String from) {
        String[] data = from.split(",");
        return new Person(Integer.parseInt(data[0]), data[1], new Date(data[2]));
    }
```

Comment: You should have a look at json parsers like jacksonxml for such tasks.

Comment: The json array is not correct. What is that object inside json array - a `string` or an `json`  object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like so,

```
Pattern idNumber = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
List<Person> persons = Arrays.stream(from.split("}")).filter(s -> idNumber.matcher(s).find())
    .map(s -> s.substring(s.indexOf("{") + 1)).map(s -> s.split(","))
    .map(a -> new Person(Integer.parseInt(a[0].replaceAll("\"", "")), a[1],
        LocalDateTime.parse(a[2].trim().replaceAll("\"", ""))))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

First `split` each string using "}" character, and then filter out invalid tokens, which does not contain a digit. Notice that each valid payload should contain Id number which is a digit. Finally remove any spurious trailing characters occur before the Id digit and map each resulting `String` to a `Person` object. At last `collect` the `Person` instances into a `List`.

Notice that I have used `LocalDateTime` for the `dateOfBirth` field in the `Person` class. So the `Person` class looks like this.

```
public class Person {
    private final Integer id;
    private final String name;
    private final LocalDateTime dateOfBirth;
    // remainder omitted for the sake of brevity.
}
```

However as you can see it is always intuitive to use some framework such as Jackson `ObjectMapper` to get the work done than writing all this. But in this case your Json is malformed so you won't be able to use such a framework unless you fix the json payload structure.

**Update**

Here's much more elegant Java9 solution.

```
String regexString = Pattern.quote("{\"") + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote("\"}");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexString);

List<Person> persons = pattern.matcher(from)
        .results()
        .map(mr -> mr.group(1)).map(s -> s.split(", "))
        .map(a -> new Person(Integer.parseInt(a[0]), a[1], LocalDateTime.parse(a[2])))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In Java 9, you can now use `Matcher#results()` to get a `Stream<MatchResult>`. Here's an excerpt from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--).

> Returns a stream of match results for each subsequence of the input
>   sequence that matches the pattern. The match results occur in the same
>   order as the matching subsequences in the input sequence.

I would rather recommend you to use Java9 to solve this.

If you need to do it just for a `List` of `String` representation of a `Person`, you may do it like so.

```
List<String> personStr = Arrays.asList("1, Franck, 1980-01-01T00:00:00", "2, Marc, 1981-01-01T00:00:00");
List<Person> persons = personStr.stream()
        .map(s -> s.replaceAll(" ", "").split(","))
        .map(a -> new Person(Integer.parseInt(a[0]), a[1], LocalDateTime.parse(a[2])))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Notice the latter is far more easier than the prior and contains just a subset of the original solution.

Comment: Thanks Ravindra, it makes total sense!
However would you have any idea how to do it if you had a List<String> as a parameter to convert to a List<Person> ?

Comment: @Andrew Show me your input list, and then I can update the answer.

Comment: Given I am using SpringBoot, I was thinking of using a wrapper so I could map the RequestBody to this wrapper automatically and then convert it to a List<Person>:

public class PersonsWrapper {
 private List<String> persons;
}

So each String in this list would look like this: "2, Marc, 1981-01-01T00:00:00"

Comment: Mate you're awesome! I haven't used java for a while, it's so nice to be able to convert it this way!

Answer (score 1):

An Extention of your solution itself & with a bit of abstraction:

```
List<String> personStr = Arrays.asList("1, Franck, 1980-01-01T00:00:00", "2, Marc, 1981-01-01T00:00:00");

List<Person> persons = personStr.stream()
            .map(Person::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Where, `Person` class has a constructor which accepts a `string` arg to convert it to a `Person` object, as follows:

```
public Person(String from) {
    String[] data = from.split(",");
    Arrays.parallelSetAll(data, i -> data[i].trim());
    this.id = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
    this.name = data[1];
    this.dateOfBirth = new Date(data[2]);
}
```